# Translate data that retrieved from database

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

Currently I am building a multi-language page which some data on the page are retrieved from database. I use i18n to translate static content but I don't know how to translate the mentioned data.

frontend

```
<div th:each="map : ${listTypeMap}">
     <div th:each="mapEntry : ${map}" th:if="${mapEntry.value} == 'foo'">
          <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" th:value="${mapEntry.key}" required>
             <label class="form-check-label" for="validationFormCheck1" th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></label>
             //I want to translate this label
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have a naive idea which is get the current webpage locale and translate it in spring, but I think that there are better ways.

SearchFooServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SearchFooServiceImpl implements SearchFooService{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public HashMap<String,String> searchFoo() {
        HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();
        jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT FOO_NAME_ENG, FOO_CLASS_DESC_ENG FROM FOO_TYPE ", (ResultSet rs) -> {
            Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            //if locale.getLanguage() is zh, translate English to Chinese
            while (rs.next()) {
                results.put(rs.getString("FOO_NAME_ENG"), rs.getString("FOO_CLASS_DESC_ENG"));
            }
            return results;
        });
        return results;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is using thymeleaf preprocessor.
For example, data I get from database is like "Hello World", then I convert it to "hello.world" by the following code

```
th:text="#{__${#strings.replace(mapEntry.key,' ','.').toLowerCase()}__}"
```

Then I can translate it like normal text in i18n.

message_en.prperties

```
hello.world = Hello World
```

message_zh_HK.prperties

```
hello.world = \u4f60\u597d\u4e16\u754c
```